# jquery cannot be show the number of textbox in modal

Tags: jquery

//my page code:
// here i input the value that i wanted to display a number of textbox

```
                       number: <input type='text' name='txtnumb' />
                      <input type="button" name='show' value="show" />

                       <?php include_once('modal.php'); ?>

                       <script>
                       $('input[name=show]').on('click', function(){
                       $('input[name=totaltxtbox]').val($('input[name=txtnumb]').val());    
                       $('#modal').modal('show');
                       });

                       </script>
```

//inside the modal.php

```
                <div class="modal" role="dialog" id="modalbox" aria-hidden="true">
                       <input name="totaltxtbox" type="text" /> 
                        </div>
```

// why it wont show the number of textbox that i want to display as many as i wanted??...

Comment: Try wrapping jQuery code inside jQuery(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: try to log/alert the value of `$('input[name=totaltxtbox]').length` in the click handler